# htaccess to not show index.php in sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, indexing

I have a simple page structure like below

/directory/subdir_1/index.php

/directory/subdir_2/index.php

....

(there are no other files in these directories)

is it possible to have 'fake/pretty' urls for the above files as below?

/directory/subdir_1

/directory/subdir_2

...

so this path would show whether the visitor typed that,/directory/subdir_2/ or /directory/subdir_2/index.php.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at the top of index.php to get the address and if the string ends with index.php redirect them. However, I would suggest not necessarily doing this and leaving it. Just change the links on your page to not include index.php.

Comment: As you say prob not the nicest way of doing it, i do have the urls not pointing to index.php, however all 3 potential versions of the url are ending up in my webmaster tools, and so i get the feeling having links to my site spread over those three versions could be compromising them.

Comment: @Jamesaa there is nothing to compromise

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

in your .conf or .htaccess file, it should do that anyway. see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex

Comment: Thanks, it does but that is not exactly what i am trying to achieve - i want it to not show the url finishing in /index.php even if thats what you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

Question is too unclear to me.
but by default web-server works as you described:

Both `/directory/subdir_2/` or `/directory/subdir_2/index.php` would run index.php from the `/directory/subdir_2/`.

If you want to redirect a client in case it requests `/directory/subdir_2/index.php`, to the `/directory/subdir_2/` you'd better not to do it. Just have all links on your site without trailing index.php.

Comment: Thanks, it does work as above all three versions would register the page, but i want whichever url you type to end up just as /directory/subdir_1 

Sorry if it wasnt clear enough