# Using .htaccess, never show index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I never show index.php?  For example, all requests to
**site.com/index.php/controller** are redirected in the browser address bar to
 **site.com/controller**?

My current .htaccess removes index.php but when a user directly types **site.com/index.php/controller** they are still shown that address in the address bar as opposed to **site.com/controller**

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

NOTE:  Before flaming, I have checked lots of .htaccess threads that solve redirecting index.php but I haven't found one to never show index.php.  Here are a few...
[Not Show index.php in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865412/htaccess-to-not-show-index-php-in-sub-directory)
[remove index.php in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192136/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Anyone able to shed light on this?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if you get a request for this /index.php/controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/controller$
#redirect to  just controller
RewriteRule . controller     [R=301,L]
```

If you need this to work for any path_info use the rule below instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if you get a request for this /index.php(any-path)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/(.+)$
#redirect to  any-path
RewriteRule . %1     [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think ```site.com/index.php/controller``` was just an example... he surely needs placeholders.

Comment: I have tried this but with no luck.  Additionally I am working with the Codeigniter framework but I don't believe that would make a difference.  Thanks but any other ideas?  And yes on the placeholders.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You're not getting redirected or you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: I am not being redirected.  If I access site.comp/index.php/controller that remains in the address bar as opposed to being taken to site.com/controller.  Thanks for the help and any ideas are appreciated to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)% ^/$1 [QSA,R]
```

I have not tested this, but as I understand it, it will take an URL with index.php as the filename (regardless of anything following it) and redirect it to /(.*) (i.e. anything that followed index.php in the original request). The QSA flag appends the query string, and R makes it a hard Redirect rather than just rewriting the URL on the current request.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a more generalized solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

#Disallow listing contents of subfolders
Options All -Indexes

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If index or index.php requested, strip and redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index(\\.php)?
RewriteRule ^index(\\.php)?$ http://yourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

## Part 1
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## Part 2 - handle incoming that lacks extension (except for existing folders)
## To redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php, (skip for admin or user dirs)
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```