# Hide file extension (.php) in .htaccess file

Tags: php

I know there are many topics. I tried them many times, but it doesn't work.

#### What do I want?

Instead of `example.com/en/file.php`, users see only `example.com/en/file`.

#### My [.htaccess file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine on
*RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php*


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ru\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/ru\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^en\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]
```

*etc. for every language*

1. What do I have to add to hide extensions?
2. After it works, should I use links between pages as "file.php" or only "file"?

Comment: Check the `RewriteRule` syntax - it's the opposite. The first is "what to rewrite", the second is "the result of rewriting"

Comment: This has to be the most asked question that I have seen on SO, it does not hurt to perform a search prior to posting

Comment: This is like hacking, you are always better off using a simple PHP framework. Try [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) if you would like to give it a shot :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298787/using-htaccess-never-show-index-php/31492764#31492764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$      $1.php     [L,QSA]
```

In your links, don't use extensions.

Comment: adding: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L] //doesn't works: The requested URL /q_insert_city_image was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /en/things_to_visit was not found on this server. I don't understand why it doesn't work =(

Comment: Did a little test and it worked. Make sure that you can use `mod_rewrite`, and that `/en/things_to_visit.php` really exists.

Comment: hmmmm, may be it is not enabled.. I can't see it here: http://www.incinqueterre.com/1.php in phpinfo. I thought that "url_rewriter.tags" was enough... Will think tomorrow, now I have to leave

Comment: but with "hide index.php" it works, so its enabled... :/ ohhhh

Comment: I tried this: RewriteRule ^(.*)\.p$ $1.php [L,QSA] and it works from .p to .php but without extension no +_+

Comment: Sorry for my spam, just checked on other host and your code works! So, it's a problem of my host... I'll send them a ticket now

Comment: Yes, thank you ;) By adding 1 line: Options -Multiviews // it now works on my host too, that was a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this.
Modify as you see fit for more specific pattern matching.

```
RewriteRule ^(?:(.*)/)?(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1
```

Rewrites:

/en/fun => /fun.php?lang=en

/ru/fun => /fun.php?lang=ru

/fun => /fun.php?lang=

Comment: Language is ok.. I like it more with folder visible

Comment: @ЖеняТест Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding one line:

```
RewriteEngine on
**Options -Multiviews**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$      $1.php     [L,QSA]
```